# NullPointerException in ExpandableListView for Child Items

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Am getting NullPointerException When I click on parent item. Can you please suggest for this reason by seeing my code.I am not getting anything next step what I have to take for this mistake.Try to suggest me by seeing my code.The screen shot of logcat also I posted here.

Thanks in Advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nansL.png)

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Group> groups;

ImageLoader imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
    this.context = context;
    this.groups = groups;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
    NetworkImageView iv = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.flag);

    tv.setText(child.getName().toString());
    iv.setImageUrl(String.valueOf(child.getImage()), imageLoader);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
    tv.setText(group.getName());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: Can you just post xml code of `child_item`?

Comment: Yes I posted but the thing ,I dont want to display any image just i want to display a text. Even in my web service also there is no image

Comment: Then in child_item why you are using ImageView object?

Comment: Yes It is there but even If I remove also it wont work

Comment: The id `country_name` doesn't exist in the child_item xml. Instead of that use `name`.

Comment: Now It works,Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using different id for textview in `getChildView` method

```
TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
```

and

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
```

this produce nullpointerexception.Therefore change it to

```
TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
```